# How to calculate the number of items running on sigma of "for" loop

Tags: math, language-agnostic

I have the following code and I need to calculate the sigmas.
I know to calculate the first sigma, I don't know the second sigma.
I don't know how to calculate the numbers that being sum.

[image]

Can someone explain me how to calculate the numbers in the second sigma, from `k = 1 to ?`

Thanks

Comment: could you make it more clear on what you want to find?

Comment: Please pick one language, not 4.

Comment: I think the OP wants to know "given the above code, what's the mathemathical expression whose value it calculates?" Where they already know part of it and provided it in the picture.

Comment: the second sigma is not a standard sigma, the standard sigma has the increment of `1` but the second sigma has the increment of `i*i`, so the answer is NO. You can't write it so, in fact the `?` is `n*n`, but if so we understand that the increment is `1` but it's not.

Comment: Well you can see the upper limit of k is n*n i.e k=1 to n*n

Comment: The second sigma sign is always from `1 to n*n` but increments are dependent on `i` value

Comment: And, more annoyingly, there doesn't seem to be a way to express `n²` as a sum of `i²` terms.

Comment: @boxed__l The problem here is there is no such thing as "increment by `i`". Not in the usual sum notation.

Comment: someone told me:
"k is being increments in steps of i^2, how much time it will take to go to n^2 ?

num of steps = (number to reach)/(size of step) = n^2 /i^2           "

is it make any sense?

Comment: @DanHunex That's nonsense. Clearly the sum of all numbers between 1 and n*n is a different number than the sum of *some* numbers in that interval. (And incrementing by `i²` will skip some numbers.)

Comment: @togitog Well, can you handwave it by writing [`floor(n²/i²)`](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cleft%20%5Clfloor%20%7Bn%5E2%7D%20%5Cover%20%7Bi%5E2%7D%20%5Cright%20%5Crfloor) as the upper limit?

Comment: @millimoose, pay attension it increments by k+i² and not i²

Comment: @togitog ...Right. Oh well.

Comment: @millimoose, and no, I can't handwave it, I don't understand the reason he told me about it

Comment: @boxed__l You can use whatever you want in the second sigma, I just can't tell if the result will be correct by looking, that's for the OP to say. Test and make a full answer?

Comment: @millimoose, I edit my question and add the answer, I think this is the correct answer, it make sense for me, what you think ?

Comment: @togitog; It is completely wrong!!! On each iteration value of `i` will change and it will not give `1+mi^2` on the **m** run.

Comment: @haccks : no it won't. `i*i` would be a factor of `k` on the mth run.

Comment: @boxed__l; What I am saying that: here OP generates the pattern by simply adding `i^2` to each iteration but in each iteration `i` has different value and you can't add it like this. For example in first iteration `i = log(n)` and in last `i = sqrt(n)` (sorry for `sqrt`).

Comment: @haccks, ok not the m run when k=m, I meant on the series:  
1+i^2, 1+2i^2, ...,1+mi^2,...,n^2

You have the m time and according to that we can understand the limit of the sigma, know ?

Comment: @togitog; Know. Again you are thinking in a wrong direction.

Comment: @hacks : What is the proper approach? @togitog `sum` can be added with a value of `j` where `j` is the number of times the 2nd loop should run thereby eliminating the need for the 2nd loop and the second sigma

Comment: @togitog If you want to self-answer your question, please add a new answer, don't edit your original question.

Comment: @boxed__l; Wait for edit in my answer. I am working on it to explain it easily.

Comment: @togitog; Tell me about type of `i` whether it is `int` or `float` or something else. Also is there any value for `n` is given?

Comment: @hacks : I think they should be Integers not floating point values. Isn't the question language-agnostic?

Comment: @togitog; Read my updated answer.

Comment: Hmmm, ... commentors to this question include *N*-ithin *N*-ayagam, *K*-ing *K*-ing, *m*-illi-*m*-oose and the OP, *t*-ogi *t*-og.  I wonder what the sigma on *that* is?

Answer (score 0):

For clearness, let's rewrite the second loop as this:

```
int j;
for (j = 1; k(j) <= n*n; j++) ;
```

We want to know the value of `j` at the end of the loop, without executing it.

Notice that `k(j)` satisfies:

- `k(1)` = 1
- `k(j+1) = k(j) + i*i`

You can see that `k(j) = 1 + j * i * i` satisfies these conditions.

Hence the loop is equivalent to:

```
int j = floor ((n*n - 1) / (i*i)) + 1
```

The external loop can not be written in a closed form.